# Use laptop microphone as android microphone

Tags: laptop, android, microphone

I want to use my laptop microphone as the input voice for my android so when I make a call in my android I can use my laptop microphone. Is there any solution to use the laptop microphone in andoird devices?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -1):

[WO Mic:](https://wolicheng.com/womic/index.html)    [Linux (AppImage)](https://wolicheng.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html)    [Android (Play Store)](https://wolicheng.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html)    [iOS (App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1260978417)

[image: Diagram]

Comment: The Android link is the same as Linux one. Here is the actual link: https://wolicheng.com/womic/download.html

Comment: Also this shows how to use your phone as a microphone. The question is about using th laptop as a microphone for the phone.